# How to upload files in several places in Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to upload 3 pdf files to different 3 places in turn. But in my case only first file is uploaded. The rest opens the Browse, but the files were not uploaded. Just stuck on file upload form. If manually click "Cancel" in chromedriver, it will continue uploading third file and same error. Second and Third files are not appeared in Browse. But chromedriver thinks that they attached. And if I click "Cancel" instead of "Upload", the test result is success without two files. No error messages.

I tried to create a methods to upload for each file. But nothing has changed.

HTML code for file attach:

```
<div id="ide5" data-uid="modal:dialog:document-upload-form-panel" data-better-uid="windows-holder:modal:dialog:document-upload-form-panel">
  <span class="fileinput-button">
    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple="multiple">
  </span>
  <input type="button" class="medium-button multiupload-select" name="formContent:documentUploadFormPanel:addFiles" id="ide6" value="Добавить файлы" data-uid="modal:dialog:document-upload-form-panel:add-files" data-better-uid="windows-holder:modal:dialog:document-upload-form-panel:add-files">
  <table class="multiupload-files"></table>
</div>
```

I'm using `<input type="file" name="files[]" multiple="multiple">` to attach files

Here is the file upload code:

```
enum docElements{ incomeStatement, gcvp, personalData}

@И("^Сделать: «(.*)»$")
public void loanAssignParameters(docElements docs) throws InterruptedException {

    String  doc1 = "C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\Autotest_dev\\client_docs\\file1.pdf",
            doc2 = "C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\Autotest_dev\\client_docs\\file2.pdf",
            doc3 = "C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\Autotest_dev\\client_docs\\file3.pdf";

    switch(docs) {
        case incomeStatement:
            $(By.name("panesContainer:1:paneContent:panesContainer:2:paneContent:consentDocumentsContainer:consentDocuments:1:checked")).shouldBe(visible).click();
            $(By.xpath("//div[@data-uid='kz-2sp-1bo-d-personal-information-section-pane:base-product-consent-documents-pane:consent-documents-container:1']/ul/li[3]/a[2]")).click();
            $(By.xpath("//div[@data-uid='modal:dialog:document-upload-form-panel']/span/input")).sendKeys(incomeStatementDoc); //first file attached and uploaded
            $(By.name("buttonPanel:ok")).click();
            break;

        case gcvp:
            $(By.name("panesContainer:1:paneContent:panesContainer:2:paneContent:consentDocumentsContainer:consentDocuments:2:checked")).shouldBe(visible).click();
            $(By.xpath("//div[@data-uid='kz-2sp-1bo-d-personal-information-section-pane:base-product-consent-documents-pane:consent-documents-container:2']/ul/li[3]/a[2]")).click();
            $(By.xpath("//div[@data-uid='modal:dialog:document-upload-form-panel']/span/input")).sendKeys(gcvpDoc); //second file not attached
            $(By.name("buttonPanel:ok")).click();
            break;

        case personalData:
            $(By.name("panesContainer:1:paneContent:panesContainer:2:paneContent:consentDocumentsContainer:consentDocuments:3:checked")).shouldBe(visible).click();
            $(By.xpath("//div[@data-uid='kz-2sp-1bo-d-personal-information-section-pane:base-product-consent-documents-pane:consent-documents-container:3']/ul/li[3]/a[2]")).click();
            $(By.xpath("//div[@data-uid='modal:dialog:document-upload-form-panel']/span/input")).sendKeys(personalDataDoc); //third file not attached
            $(By.name("buttonPanel:ok")).click();
            break;
        default:
            Assert.fail("Chosen option to go not written in code");
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Comment: Hello, thaks for comment. I updated question :)

Answer (score 0):

Found how to fix

When uploading the second and third files, I set `Thread.sleep(1000);` at every step